# Maximum value from previous row based on rolling period pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have dataset as below:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID':  ['27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '48002', '48002', '48002'],
        'Invoice_Date': ['2020-06-26', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-14', '2020-07-25', 
                         '2020-07-30', '2020-08-02', '2020-05-13', '2020-06-20', '2020-06-28'],
        'Payment_Term': [7,8,3,6,4,7,8,5,3,6],
        'Payment_Date': ['2020-07-05', '2020-07-05','2020-07-03', '2020-07-21', '2020-07-31', 
                         '2020-08-15', '2020-08-22', '2020-06-16', '2020-06-23', '2020-07-05'],
        'Due_Date': ['2020-07-03', '2020-07-07', '2020-07-03', '2020-07-20', '2020-07-29', 
                         '2020-08-06', '2020-08-10', '2020-05-18', '2020-06-23', '2020-07-04'],
        'Delay': [2,-2,0,1,2,9,12,29,0,1],
        'Difference_Date': [0,3,1,14,11,5,3,0,38,8],
        })
data
```

I need to add another column `Max` that shows the maximum value from previous `Delay` row. It will have another condition that is, it should be a 30 days rolling period. Meaning that, for `Max` in current row will take the maximum delay from previous row that is in the 30 days period from the current row `Invoice_Date`.

The output desired is:

```
ID     Invoice_Date Payment_Term  Payment_Date       Due_Date  Delay    Difference_Date           Max

27459    2020-06-26            7    2020-07-05     2020-07-03      2                  0             0
27459    2020-06-29            8    2020-07-05     2020-07-07     -2                  3             2
27459    2020-06-30            3    2020-07-03     2020-07-03      0                  1             2
27459    2020-07-14            6    2020-07-21     2020-07-20      1                  14            2  
27459    2020-07-25            4    2020-07-31     2020-07-29      2                  11            2
27459    2020-07-30            7    2020-08-15     2020-08-06      9                  5             2
27459    2020-08-02            8    2020-08-22     2020-08-10      12                 3             9
48002    2020-05-13            5    2020-06-16     2020-05-18      29                 0             0
48002    2020-06-20            3    2020-06-23     2020-06-23      0                  38           29
48002    2020-06-28            6    2020-07-05     2020-07-04      1                  8            29
```

Comment: this is not ordered by invoice date

Comment: The invoice date is ordered based on the ID

Comment: i see.  do you want this grouped by id, also?

Comment: yes, it need to be grouped by id

Comment: it looks like the last elements of `Max` are wrong: 29 is not within a 30 day window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to do that:

```
data['Invoice_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Invoice_Date'])
groups = data.groupby('ID')

for group_name, df_group in groups:
    for idx,row in df_group.iterrows():
        dt_range = pd.date_range(row['Invoice_Date'] - pd.to_timedelta(30, 'day'), row['Invoice_Date'])[:-1]
        data.loc[idx, 'max'] = df_group[df_group.Invoice_Date.isin(dt_range)].Delay.max()

print(data)
```

Output:

```
      ID Invoice_Date  Payment_Term Payment_Date    Due_Date  Delay    Difference_Date  max  
0  27459   2020-06-26             7   2020-07-05  2020-07-03      2                  0  NaN  
1  27459   2020-06-29             8   2020-07-05  2020-07-07     -2                  3  2.0  
2  27459   2020-06-30             3   2020-07-03  2020-07-03      0                  1  2.0  
3  27459   2020-07-14             6   2020-07-21  2020-07-20      1                 14  2.0  
4  27459   2020-07-25             4   2020-07-31  2020-07-29      2                 11  2.0  
5  27459   2020-07-30             7   2020-08-15  2020-08-06      9                  5  2.0  
6  27459   2020-08-02             8   2020-08-22  2020-08-10     12                  3  9.0  
7  48002   2020-05-13             5   2020-06-16  2020-05-18     29                  0  NaN  
8  48002   2020-06-20             3   2020-06-23  2020-06-23      0                 38  NaN  
9  48002   2020-06-28             6   2020-07-05  2020-07-04      1                  8  0.0
```

You can fill up NaNs with `data.fillna(0)`. See that the first values for ID "48002" are NaN because the previous values are not in a 30-days range.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rolling` method for operations regarding only some past elements. However, the dates should be monotonic (ascending or descending), which means the dates should be sorted.

You can try the following:

```
df['Invoice_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice_Date'])
df.set_index('Invoice_Date', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

df['max'] = df.groupby('ID')['Delay'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling('30D', closed='left').max())
```

Edit: As suggested by @Cainã, a `groupby` was included to guarantee this process is done separately for each unique `ID`

The `closed` parameter is needed to especify that the current day should not be included.

The new dataframe is as follows (here it is sorted by `Invoice_Date` only)

```
                 ID  Delay  Max
Invoice_Date                   
2020-05-13    48002     29  NaN
2020-06-20    48002      0  NaN
2020-06-26    27459      2  NaN
2020-06-28    48002      1  0.0
2020-06-29    27459     -2  2.0
2020-06-30    27459      0  2.0
2020-07-14    27459      1  2.0
2020-07-25    27459      2  2.0
2020-07-30    27459      9  2.0
2020-08-02    27459     12  9.0
```

If we sort this by `ID` as well (by running `df.reset_index().sort_values(['ID','Invoice_Date'])`), we get:

```
                 ID  Delay  Max
Invoice_Date                   
2020-05-13    48002     29  NaN
2020-06-20    48002      0  NaN
2020-06-26    27459      2  NaN
2020-06-28    48002      1  0.0
2020-06-29    27459     -2  2.0
2020-06-30    27459      0  2.0
2020-07-14    27459      1  2.0
2020-07-25    27459      2  2.0
2020-07-30    27459      9  2.0
2020-08-02    27459     12  9.0
```

Comment: I think this does not meet the requirements - he wants the 30 days *excluding* the current row

Comment: Sorry you're right, I missed that. I've corrected it already

Comment: Awesome @Ralubrusto! It avoids unnecessary `for loops` +1. Although it still doesn't fit the OP requirements. Consider editing your answer to include a  `groupby` statement.

Comment: For instance, just out curiosity something like: `df['max'] = df.groupby('ID')['Delay'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling('30D', closed='left').max())` plus `df.reset_index().sort_values(['ID','Invoice_Date'])` results in the exact output of my approach. But here it's way faster!

Comment: Great suggestion @CainãMaxCouto-Silva! I was struggling to include a `groupby('ID')`, but this really works!

Answer (score 1):

`df.rolling` can get the job done and is probably the most performant.

```
df["Invoice_Date"] = df.Invoice_Date.astype("datetime64")    
df["Max"] = df.groupby("ID").rolling("30d", on="Invoice_Date", closed="left").Delay.max().values
```

result:

```
      ID Invoice_Date  Payment_Term Payment_Date    Due_Date  Delay  Difference_Date  Max
0  27459   2020-06-26             7   2020-07-05  2020-07-03      2                0  NaN
1  27459   2020-06-29             8   2020-07-05  2020-07-07     -2                3  2.0
2  27459   2020-06-30             3   2020-07-03  2020-07-03      0                1  2.0
3  27459   2020-07-14             6   2020-07-21  2020-07-20      1               14  2.0
4  27459   2020-07-25             4   2020-07-31  2020-07-29      2               11  2.0
5  27459   2020-07-30             7   2020-08-15  2020-08-06      9                5  2.0
6  27459   2020-08-02             8   2020-08-22  2020-08-10     12                3  9.0
7  48002   2020-05-13             5   2020-06-16  2020-05-18     29                0  NaN
8  48002   2020-06-20             3   2020-06-23  2020-06-23      0               38  NaN
9  48002   2020-06-28             6   2020-07-05  2020-07-04      1                8  0.0
```

Comment: It's quite elegant to sum everything up in two single lines. But this throws an error for me (Same as [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13966)). What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: `pd.__version__` -> 1.1.4

Comment: thanks @Ralubrusto :)  I was actually thinking it's a bit unreadable.  Probably performant though!

Comment: I was using `1.0.5`. Upgrading to the latest version made it work perfectly. Well done! :)

Comment: Great answer. I'm still unsure how `.rolling()` works under the hood (regarding data order) when using `groupby`, but I've added an extra line with 27459 as ID, and it seems it messes up the result. So I would recommend to sort group-dates before applying it (e.g. `df = df.sort_values(['ID','Invoice_Date'])`). Anyways, well done!

Comment: If the datetime column for rolling is not sorted it should fail.  Can you provide an explicit example of it messing up?